# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo(class: MainActivity)

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

I am getting this Exception while launching my app on emulator
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo(class: MainActivity): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #31: Binary XML file line #19: Error inflating class fragment

at this line

```
ViewFlipper list = view.findViewById(R.id.newList);
```

My affected layout

```
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        android:paddingHorizontal="16dp"
        android:paddingVertical="8dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/test"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/test_up"
            android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" /> 

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="400dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/limitPageSize">
    android:id="@+id/newlist"


</LinearLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: post your logcat message where is displayed "Caused by...". Is this the same layout loaded by MainActivity using setContentView(...) ?

Comment: android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)

Comment: Could you post more code?

Comment: added above code

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a container for your fragment, but the amount of code posted makes this a little unclear.

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments

You could host fragments in your view like this (from the docs):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <fragment android:name="com.example.news.ArticleListFragment"
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <fragment android:name="com.example.news.ArticleReaderFragment"
            android:id="@+id/viewer"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Or you could just use a FrameLayout.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/newList"
        android:layout_width="400dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/limitPageSize">

      <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

In .xml replace that

```
android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
```

with

```
androidx.constraintlayout.widget.
```

and in app.gradle add in dependencies

```
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.2'
```

[image]